# How can I get PowerShell to use the arguments passed on the script to run successfully?

Tags: powershell

I have written a script to remotely update a machine and am currently passing the username,password and path on the script itself as arguments but it still prompts me for the username and password to connect to the remote machine. Where am i going wrong?

```
    [string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$credentials=$args[0]
    [string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$password=$args[1]
    $destination =$args[2] 
    $destinationHome =$args[3]
    $sourcePathBat = $args[4] 
    $sourcePathZip = $args[5]
    $command = "cmd.exe /c \\192.168.50.23\deployment\deploy-smartcheck-kiosk.bat upgrade"
    $secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Params = New-Object System.management.automation.PSCredential($credentials, $secPassword)

    Write-Host $args[0]
    Write-Host $args[1]
    Write-Host $args[2]
    Write-Host $args[3]
    Write-Host $args[4]
    Write-Host $args[5]

    net use $destination $secPassword /USER:$credentials

    Copy-Item -Path $sourcePathBat -Destination $destinationHome;

    Copy-Item -Path $sourcePathZip -Destination $destinationHome;

    Write-Host "Performing remote command..."
    Write-Host $command

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName 192.168.50.23 -Credential $Params -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
    param($command)
    Write-Host "Trying to execute remote command ($command)"
    Invoke-Expression -Command: "$command"
    } -ArgumentList $command
```

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit..."

Updated script with a couple of changes

This is how i am currently running the script:
        & '.\execute-copy-and-command - Copy.ps1' test test2 test3 test4

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting that part after `Enter-PSSession` run on other computer?

Comment: @PetSerAl I am remotely transferring files from my machine to a another one on the same domain. The only thing that runs on the other machine will be the Invoke-Command onwards.

Answer (score 0):

1. `[PSCredential]` object requires password as securesctring...here $args[1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/) should be of type System.Security.SecureString.

   2. `Enter-PSSession` is used for interactive PowerShell sessions and using it in a script doesn't make sense. Whatever you kept after that will not be running in the remote machine(PS V 2), if running will be running in localmachine.

you can have a check [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/)

Regards,

Kvprasoon

Comment: So i changed my script according to your first point. But I still get an error when calling the Invoke-Command with the credential. 


    '    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (192.168.50.23:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionStateBroken'



Also, i made sure that on each of the machines, the other is added as a trustedHost.